# How to group a column by specific string and create a new column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

right now I have a data frame that looks like this

| Time | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1:00 | White |
| 5:43 | Orange |
| 7:29 | Black |
| 9:56 | White |
| 9:43 | White |
| 7:43 | Yellow |
| 9:29 | Black |
| 2:34 | White |

and I want the end result to look like this

| Time | Color | Cumulative Count of White |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1:00 | White | 1 |
| 5:43 | Orange | 1 |
| 7:29 | Black | 1 |
| 9:56 | White | 2 |
| 9:43 | White | 3 |
| 7:43 | Yellow | 3 |
| 9:29 | Black | 3 |
| 2:34 | White | 4 |

I have already tried

`df1['Cumulative Count of White'] = df1.groupby('Color').cumcount()+1`

but I don't know how to count only certain color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an extra step after the cumulative computation:

```
temp = df.assign(cum_white = df.groupby('Color').Color.cumcount().add(1))

temp.cum_white = np.where(temp.Color.eq('White'), temp.cum_white, np.nan)

temp.ffill()

   Time   Color  cum_white
0  1:00   White        1.0
1  5:43  Orange        1.0
2  7:29   Black        1.0
3  9:56   White        2.0
4  9:43   White        3.0
5  7:43  Yellow        3.0
6  9:29   Black        3.0
7  2:34   White        4.0
```